# Device Not Listed In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, device, adb

I know there's a ton of posts on this subject but none of them have helped me so far. Recently I did a clean install of my computer and now my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc isn't showing up in my list of devices in Eclipse (it did show up before I reinstalled my computer). Now, to fix it I've tried the following:

1. Install latest drivers from Google SDK/Sony Ericsson developer website (windows told me that my drivers were already up to date).
2. Turn on USB Debugging (I am 100% sure it is turned on. I tried switching it off and on again, didn't help).
3. Install all SDK updates available (At this point I was trying anything but this didn't help either).
4. Run adb devices (It says "List of devices attached" but the list is blank)
5. Manually add the vendor ID in the adb_usb file
6. Kill the adb-server and start it again

None of the above have had any results. My device is still not listed in adb devices and thus also doesn't show up in my devices list in Eclipse. Does anybody know of anything else I can try to solve this problem? I'd really like to get on with developing apps again.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, I do see my android phone in My Computer. I can move files onto it etc.

**EDIT 2:**

I think the issue is being caused by conflicting drivers. When I look into my driver file details I see:

WpdMtpDr.dll

winusb.sys

WUDFRd.sys

WpdMtp.dll

WpdMtpUS.dll

Should there be five entries? I don't know much about this but after having researched a bit I think maybe if I would remove WpdMtpDr.dll it would solve the problem. However, it is located in system32 and I don't like removing stuff there unless I'm sure of what I'm doing. Does anybody know if this is indeed likely to be the cause?

**EDIT 3:**

I **FINALLY** fixed it after being stuck on this forever, so I'll post my solution in case anybody comes across the same problem. What I did was actually pretty simple. Just go to the device manager and right click on "Xperia Arc S" which for me was listed under "Portable Devices". Click "Update driver software", then "Browse my computer for driver software", then "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer". Now double click "USB Composite Device". After this open adb devices and restart the adb server (or just restart your pc, that should work as well). This fixed it for me, so if you have the same problem I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried changing the cable?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in EDIT 3: worked for me.

> Just go to the device manager and right click on "Xperia Arc S" which for me was listed under "Portable Devices". Click "Update driver software", then "Browse my computer for driver software", then "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer". Now double click "USB Composite Device".

I had problems with Asus Memo Pad and Windows 7. Now adb finally works.

Comment: Worked for me aswell! Couldn't find my Sony Xperia Arc S but now I can.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, can you make other actions with the device when it's connected to you pc?
like moving photos/music from the device and to it?

If not then I think it's either a drives issue or as mentioned a malfunctioning cable and I would definitely replace the cable and set up the latest Sony drivers you can get from here:

http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/

If this package doesn't help, then I would go further and install the arc drives you can get from here:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/sony-ericsson-xperia-arc-xperia-neo-xperia-play-xperia-acro/

are you successfully running your application on the emulator?

Comment: Sorry about forgetting to mention that. I CAN move files on and off my phone, it is visible in my computer. The cable is fine, I'm pretty sure of that. I also installed both the drivers you listed there and it didn't help.

Comment: what kind of OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, oh and on the emulator everything runs fine.

Comment: please see the next link: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1065980 there is some one the encountered the same problem as yours with the same device.

Comment: I've tried to uninstall the driver for my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc, reboot my PC, plug it in and automatically let it search for a driver but this just re-installs the driver I had before so it doesn't help..